# How to return the newest file from each sub-directory in Windows command line using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using batch script for windows command line on windows 7. I am currently trying to get the newest file from each sub directory and print them to the screen. For example, if I have:

> ```
> C:\Home\Hi\Folder1\a 01/05/2016
> C:\Home\Hi\Folder1\b 01/10/2016
>
> C:\Home\Hi\Folder2\x 03/05/2016
> C:\Homeh\Hi\Folder2\y 03/1/2016
> ```

It would return: folders `b` and `x`.

I have written some script to attempt this, but it only returns the newest file in the last directory which in my example would be `x`. The script is:

```
 FOR /R "C:\Users\Maxx\Desktop\tools" %%G in (.) DO (
     Pushd %%G
     FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR %%G /B /O:D') DO SET NEWEST=%%I
          ECHO %NEWEST%
          Popd )
 Echo "back home"
```

If anyone knows how to get the newest file from each subdirectory that would be great.

Note: I have looked at various other examples such as: [Generate a list of the newest file in each subdirectory in windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143084/generate-a-list-of-the-newest-file-in-each-subdirectory-in-windows-batch), which has been very helpful in building what I have now, but ultimately it did not work.

Comment: Your code looks good except for not using Delayed Expansion.

Comment: Is the last sample folder correct as stated, or are there two typos? I mean, `C:\Home\Hi\Folder2\y 03/01/2016` rather than `C:\Homeh\Hi\Folder2\y 03/1/2016`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you are writing and reading variable `NEWEST` within the same block of code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "C:\Users\Maxx\Desktop\tools" %%G in (.) do (
    pushd "%%~G"
    for /F %%I in ('dir "%%~G" /B /O:D') do set "NEWEST=%%I"
        echo !NEWEST!
    )
    popd
echo back home
endlocal
```

Alternatively, replace `echo %NEWEST%` by `call echo %%NEWEST%%`:

```
for /R "C:\Users\Maxx\Desktop\tools" %%G in (.) do (
    pushd "%%~G"
    for /F %%I in ('dir "%%~G" /B /O:D') do set "NEWEST=%%I"
        call echo %%NEWEST%%
    )
    popd
echo back home
```

In addition, I improved quoting.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /R "C:\106x" %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd "%%G"
 SET "first="
 FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR . /a-d /B /O:-D 2^>nul') DO IF NOT DEFINED first SET first=Y&ECHO %%~dpI
 Popd 
)
Echo "back home"

GOTO :EOF
```

For each directory, go to the directory, clear a flag `first`, scan the directory for files (not directories), basic format, reverse-date order, suppressing any "file not found" reports from empty directories.

On finding the first (ie youngest) file set the flag `first` and report the filename - or parts of the filename you require.

Once `first` has been set, the report mechanism will not be invoked as `if defined` works on the *current* value of the variable.

Please note that when specifying dates, it's advisable to state the format that you are using - or at least use a date where the day number is >12, which should be adequate. For instance, your date "01/10/2016" may be interpreted as Jan 10th or Oct 1st, depending on the respondent's locale. "13/10/2016" or "10/13/2016" would make the issue obvious.